# Как в несколько раз уменьшить миниатюру (которая вставляется в записи в Wordpress) перед содержанием текста записи?

Tags: wordpress

Как в несколько раз уменьшить миниатюру (которая вставляется в записи в Wordpress) перед содержанием (вверху) текста записи? Причина в том, что миниатюра занимает больше половины территории на странице, а высота страницы в Wordpress ограничена.

Comment: К этому и предыдущему вашему вопросу: Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: Добавь в вопрос код вывода миниатюры. Или хотя бы назови тему, если эта тема из [оф каталога](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/).